# The Fortissimo topology

Tags: general-topology

In here https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Fortissimo_Space_is_T1, it was proved that the uncountable set $X$ with the Fortissimo topology is $T_1$. So, every singleton is closed.

On the other hand, every point point in $X$ except $p$ is a isolated point. So, every set $\{x\}$, $x \in X-\{p\}$ is a clopen set. Is it true?

Comment: Yes, $T_1$ guarantees that points are closed and $x$ is isolated if and only if $\{x\}$ is open.

Comment: The Fortissimo space is just the one-point Lindelöf-ication of an uncountable discrete subspace $X \setminus \{p\}$.

Answer (score 2):

Echoing the comments in hopes to have this question marked as answered.

For any point $x \neq p$, note that $p \not\in \{x\}$, so $\{x\}$ is open. Since $\{x\}$ is closed, $\{x\}$ is clopen.